# Mongoose update and save sometimes working in a nuxt vue setup

Tags: node.js, vue.js, mongoose, nuxt.js

I'm a C++ dev who inherited a node.js project which has annoying bug which is really difficult to fix with my limited mongoose expertise.

The function below get's data from a form.
It should save the data from the form and change one extra field.
The code below is probably over complicated for that goal.
But when I test this on my local machine it saves the question and changes the status perfectly but on the final server it only works 33% of the time.

Anyone can point me in the right direction here?

```
// publish 
router.put('/questions/publish/:id', passport.authenticate('jwt', 
  {session: false}), 
  async function(req, res) {
  
  var id = req.params.id
  var question = await Questions.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: req.params.id
  }, req.body);

  question = await Questions.findById(id);
  question.status = "Done"

  question.save(function() {
      res.send(question);
  })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue myself.
Wasn't related to mongoose but was an issue somewhere else.
The webpage did also trigger a edit update overwriting the publish call.